# Big unremovable bottom padding

Tags: html, css

The text have a big space in the bottom here: http://jsfiddle.net/qHaFR/

And I am not able to remove it.

Can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrapper, in this case `<span>` needs to be a block element with width and height defined.  You'll also need to change the line-height to match the height of the container.

So your style would look like:

```
#foo {
   background-color:yellow;
   font-size:260px;
   border:1px solid black;
   width: 190px; /* if display: block; */
   line-height: 200px;
   display: block; /* or inline-block */
}
```

Just to clarify, were you trying to wrap `A` in an element such as `<div>` or `<h1>` you shouldn't need to declare it `display: block` because `div` and `h1` are already block.

Comment: Works fine for me in FF14.  Did I get what you're trying to do wrong?  Are you not trying to have less space between the bottom of the `A` and the bottom border of the box?

Comment: Then I don't know what to tell you, I'm sorry.  I see a definite difference between http://jsfiddle.net/qHaFR/ and http://jsfiddle.net/qHaFR/9 in both Chrome and Firefox, even though in this case the browser shouldn't matter (though they do tend to render some sizes differently).  If anybody has an idea why the OP can't see the difference I'd love to know because that is indeed rather curious.   Also worth noting Xilexio's solution is superior because it isn't actually necessary to set the element's height and with `inline-block` it isn't necessary to set the width, either.

Comment: That's really strange because now there is a difference. Anyways, there is still some pixels.

Comment: Yes, there will be pixels.  If you wanted it to be exact you would just need to change the line-height and add padding to the top to compensate like so: http://jsfiddle.net/qHaFR/11/

Comment: But then you run into a problem because different browsers will render font size differently.  To make that work in FireFox you would need to do it like in: http://jsfiddle.net/qHaFR/12/

So really, you need to get your font-sizes to display the same size in all browsers... something way beyond the scope of this.  I'll post a link soon in an edit to this comment.

Edit:

A List Apart has a good article on the differences between how browsers will calculate font-size and how to normalize it.  That is here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `line-height` is actually that big, in order for each character to be displayable there. In some languages that space is fully used. For example, if you'd type `&Aacute;&#260;`, you'd need whole 260px. If you're okay with not being able to display those characters, you'll need to change `line-height` accordingly and display it as a block:

```
#foo
{
    background-color: yellow;
    font-size: 260px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 200px;
    display: block; /* or inline-block */  
}​
```

If you're not okay with treating it as a block (it gets 100% width then or you'll need to set it yourself), use `display: inline-block;`. Also, type `&Aacute;&#260;` instead of `A` and see that the letters get their top and bottom cut. Here, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/vmVcr/.